# scala return on first Some in list

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, scala-option

I have a list `l:List[T1]` and currently im doing the following:

```
myfun : T1 -> Option[T2]
val x: Option[T2] = l.map{ myfun(l) }.flatten.find(_=>true)
```

The `myfun` function returns None or Some, flatten throws away all the None's and find returns the first element of the list if any.

This seems a bit hacky to me. Im thinking that there might exist some for-comprehension or similar that will do this a bit less wasteful or more clever.
For example: I dont need any subsequent answers if `myfun` returns *any* `Some` during the `map` of the list `l`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
l.toStream flatMap (myfun andThen (_.toList)) headOption
```

Stream is lazy, so it won't map everything in advance, but it won't remap things either. Instead of flattening things, convert `Option` to `List` so that `flatMap` can be used.

Comment: If I'm not confused by myself, "flatMap" can be used on Option as well, so I think "andThen (_.toList)" is superfluous

Comment: val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        def fun(i : Int) = {
            if (i == 3) Some(3)
            else None
        }

        println(l.flatMap(fun(_)).head)
        println(l.flatMap(fun(_)).headOption)

Comment: results in 3 and Some(3) so it does work, or am I messing something up?

Comment: @Jens That `fun` is a `def`, not a function `T => Option[T]`.

Comment: Starting to feeling kinda dumb here .. what do you mean with its a def? It is a function from Int to Option[Int]. I can write it as val fun : (Int => Option[Int]) = (i : Int) => {
            if (i == 3) Some(3)
            else None
        }

Comment: @Jens In your example, `fun` was a method that took an `Int` and returned an `Option[Int]`. That is different than a method (or a value) that returns a function of type `Int => Option[Int]`. For a method, `l.flatMap(fun).headOption` will work. If `fun` is a function value, however, it won't. I suspect you tested it with `fun(_)` instead of just `fun` which resulted in Scala doing a partial function application, effectively creating a new function. In that context, the type inference results in implicits conversions being applied.

Comment: The more I use Scala, the more I'm in love with it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using `toStream` to make the search lazy, we can use [`Stream::collectFirst`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html#collectFirst[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Option[B]):

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8).toStream.map(myfun).collectFirst { case Some(d) => d }
// Option[String] = Some(hello)
// given def function(i: Int): Option[String] = if (i == 5) Some("hello") else None
```

This:

- Transforms the `List` into a `Stream` in order to stop the search early.
- Transforms elements using `myFun` as `Option[T]`s.
- Collects the first mapped element which is not `None` and extract it.

Starting `Scala 2.13`, with the deprecation of `Stream`s in favor of `LazyList`s, this would become:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8).to(LazyList).map(function).collectFirst { case Some(d) => d }
```

Comment: IMHO this solution is the only one that makes it clear to a casual reader that we are searching for the first Some. In the other solutions that use flatMap with Option.toList, the Option -> List conversion and flatMap obfuscates the original intent: "find the first Some"

Comment: This is how it is solved on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29234550/5826349) as well

Comment: You don't need to convert to a `Stream` for this - List also has a `collectFirst` method and you can convert the function itself into a `PartialFunction` with `Function.unlift`.

Comment: @RobinGreen If the `collectFirst` matches the first element in the list, then without a lazy sequence (stream/iterator/lazylist), you would wastefully  be applying the `function` mapping on all elements in the list even though you only really need to apply it for that first element. Also, by applying the `function` operation within the lifting part of the `collectFirst` you'd also have to apply it a second time within the mapping part of the `collectFirst` which might be wasteful if `function` is expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is *almost, but not quite*

```
val x = (l flatMap myfun).headOption
```

But you are returning a `Option` rather than a `List` from myfun, so this may not work. If so (I've no REPL to hand) then try instead:

```
val x = (l flatMap(myfun(_).toList)).headOption
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the for-comprehension equivalent is pretty easy

```
(for(x<-l, y<-myfun(x)) yield y).headOption
```

which, if you actually do the the translation works out the same as what oxbow_lakes gave.  Assuming reasonable laziness of List.flatmap, this is both a clean and efficient solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, List (i.e. collection.immutable.List) does not have lazy operations.  For reasons I don't understand, replacing `l` with `l.view` results in myfun being evaluated multiple times with the same arguments.

Comment: view is call-by-name, not lazy. If you want at-most-once evaluation, use toStream:

(l.toStream flatMap myfun).headOption

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017, the previous answers seem to be outdated. I ran some benchmarks (list of 10 million Ints, first match roughly in the middle, Scala 2.12.3, Java 1.8.0, 1.8 GHz Intel Core i5). Unless otherwise noted, `list` and `map` have the following types:

```
list: scala.collection.immutable.List
map: A => Option[B]
```

Simply call `map` on the list: ~1000 ms

```
list.map(map).find(_.isDefined).flatten
```

First call `toStream` on the list: ~1200 ms

```
list.toStream.map(map).find(_.isDefined).flatten
```

Call `toStream.flatMap` on the list: ~450 ms

```
list.toStream.flatMap(map(_).toList).headOption
```

Call `flatMap` on the list: ~100 ms

```
list.flatMap(map(_).toList).headOption
```

First call `iterator` on the list: ~35 ms

```
list.iterator.map(map).find(_.isDefined).flatten
```

Recursive function `find()`: ~25 ms

```
def find[A,B](list: scala.collection.immutable.List[A], map: A => Option[B]) : Option[B] = {
  list match {
    case Nil => None
    case head::tail => map(head) match {
      case None => find(tail, map)
      case result @ Some(_) => result
    }
  }
}
```

Iterative function `find()`: ~25 ms

```
def find[A,B](list: scala.collection.immutable.List[A], map: A => Option[B]) : Option[B] = {
  for (elem <- list) {
    val result = map(elem)
    if (result.isDefined) return result
  }
  return None
}
```

You can further speed up things by using Java instead of Scala collections and a less functional style.

Loop over indices in `java.util.ArrayList`: ~15 ms

```
def find[A,B](list: java.util.ArrayList[A], map: A => Option[B]) : Option[B] = {
  var i = 0
  while (i < list.size()) {
    val result = map(list.get(i))
    if (result.isDefined) return result
    i += 1
  }
  return None
}
```

Loop over indices in `java.util.ArrayList` with function returning `null` instead of `None`: ~10 ms

```
def find[A,B](list: java.util.ArrayList[A], map: A => B) : Option[B] = {
  var i = 0
  while (i < list.size()) {
    val result = map(list.get(i))
    if (result != null) return Some(result)
    i += 1
  }
  return None
}
```

(Of course, one would usually declare the parameter type as `java.util.List`, not `java.util.ArrayList`. I chose the latter here because it's the class I used for the benchmarks. Other implementations of `java.util.List` will show different performance - most will be worse.)

Comment: Profiling the JVM is [notoriously problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java). What benchmark tools did you use? [Thyme](https://github.com/Ichoran/thyme)? JMH? Other?

Comment: I know about the problems with Java benchmarks. I didn't use any tools, just System.nanoTime(). Each of these numbers is the average of 100 runs: start JVM, fill list with 10 million random ints, start the clock, run find() 100 times, stop the clock. Not very precise, but since there are differences of several orders of magnitude, I'd say this simple benchmark gives at least a useful rough overview of the relative performance of these approaches.

Comment: I'm travelling right now, but I hope I'll have time to upload the (very simple) code I used in the next few days. I'd love to see the same benchmarks measured by a proper tool!

Comment: By the way, some had large speed variations due to GC (e.g. toStream), others had almost no variation (e.g. iterator.map). I'd bet a more fine-grained benchmark would reproduce these numbers to within ±20% (for the ones with low variation) to ±50% (for the ones with high GC overhead).

Comment: P.S.: I used the same random seed (and thus the same 10 million random numbers) for all benchmarks.