# Coalescing options in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-option

Most SQL implementations (this question has nothing to do with SQL, it is just an example) offer the function `COALESCE(x1,x2,...,xn)` which returns `x1` if it is not `NULL`, `x2` otherwise only if `x2` is not `NULL` neither and so on. If all `xi` values are `NULL` then the result is `NULL`.

I wanted to get something like SQL's `COALESCE` in Scala for `Option` values being `NULL` replaced by `None`. I'll give you some examples:

```
> coalesce(None,Some(3),Some(4))
res0: Some(3)

> coalesce(Some(1),None,Some(3),Some(4))
res1: Some(1)

> coalesce(None,None)
res2: None
```

So I implemented it as:

```
def coalesce[T](values: Option[T]*): Option[T] = 
    (List[T]() /: values)((prev: List[T], cur: Option[T]) =>
                          prev:::cur.toList).headOption
```

It works fine but I wonder if already exists something like this function implemented as part of Scala.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644154/scala-return-on-first-some-in-list ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Shorter still, you could use `collectFirst`. This will do it in one step, with at most one traversal of the collection.

```
def coalesce[A](values: Option[A]*): Option[A] =
    values collectFirst { case Some(a) => a }


scala> coalesce(Some(1),None,Some(3),Some(4))
res15: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> coalesce(None,None)
res16: Option[Nothing] = None
```

Answer (score 14):

**Auto answer:**

The native mechanism (without implementing a `coalesce` function) is the chaining of calls to `orElse` method:

```
> None.orElse(Some(3)).orElse(Some(4))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(3)

> Some(1).orElse(None).orElse(Some(3)).orElse(Some(4))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

> None.orElse(None)
res2: Option[Nothing] = None
```

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
values.flatten.headOption
```

This works since `Option` is implicitly convertible to `Iterable`, so `flatten` works much in the same way as a list of lists.

Answer (score 3):

Find first defined option:

```
def coalesce[T](values: Option[T]*): Option[T] =
  values.find(_.isDefined).flatten
```