# Function to return first Non-None Optional

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a function that accepts 3 optional values and return first non-None optional.My code works fine but it looks bit clumsy and want to know if there is a better way to do this.
Below is my code

```
def firstNotNone[T](x: Option[T], y: Option[T], z: Option[T]): Option[T] = x.getOrElse(y.getOrElse(z.getOrElse(None))) match {
    case None =>None
    case value :T => Option(value)
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coalescing options in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234056/coalescing-options-in-scala)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `orElse` function:

```
def firstNotNone[T](x: Option[T], y: Option[T], z: Option[T]): Option[T] = 
    x.orElse(y).orElse(z)
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to `orElse` consider `collectFirst` like so

```
def firstNotNone[T](x: Option[T], y: Option[T], z: Option[T]): Option[T] =
  List(x,y,z) collectFirst { case Some(v) => v }
```

or applying comment by @pme

```
def firstNotNone[T](elems: Option[T]*): Option[T] =
  elems collectFirst { case Some(v) => v }
```

which in both cases outputs

```
firstNotNone(None, Some(3), Some(7)) // Some(3)
```

Comment: but it required additional overhead of creating a list.

Comment: @Hitesh with this you could maybe simplify and generalise your function, e.g.: `def firstNotNone[T](elems: T*): Option[T]`

Comment: @Hitesh you really should not care about the _"overhead"_ of creating a **List** of three elements. Also, as pme said, this would be a more general solution.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez and pme Now I got your point to make it.The version that pme posted looks more scalable